# D3 - Radio Buttons not Updating Data Visualization

Tags: d3.js

I have created a D3 chart which I would like to update after the user clicks on one of the radio buttons. The value of the button isn't part of the data but an update of the time range along the X axis which should update as well as Y axis data based on the newly selected timeRange value (starting point is 36 hours from "now"). I can tell from console.log statements that the timeRange is updating when the user clicks on a radio button but can't figure out what I need to do to get that chart updated (the change() function is what I am trying to use to make this happen.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtepdc/L1qf0bvk/

Here is my code:

```
const dataset = [
{
    start_date: "2019-01-27T14:30:40",
    end_date: "2019-01-27T16:32:25",
    elapsed_time: 130,
    coNum:"CO19044"
},
{
    start_date: "2019-01-27T03:05:40",
    end_date: "2019-01-27T03:32:25",
    elapsed_date: 189,
    coNum:"CO12904"
   },
   {
    start_date: "2019-01-26T22:15:40",
    end_date: "2019-01-26T23:32:25",
    elapsed_time: 89,
    coNum:"CO18345"
    },
    {
    start_date: "2019-01-26T07:00:40",
    end_date: "2019-01-26T07:40:25",
    elapsed_time: 89,
    coNum:"CO12005"
    }

];


const coNumW = window.innerWidth,
coNumH = window.innerHeight,
margin = {top: coNumH * 0.15, right: coNumW * 0.05, bottom: coNumH * 0.12, left: coNumW * 0.12},
w = coNumW - margin.left - margin.right,
h = coNumH - margin.top - margin.bottom;


const xSc = d3.scaleTime().range([0, w]),
  ySc = d3.scaleBand().range([h, 0]),
  xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xSc),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(ySc),
  filtered = [],
  dateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p");

const svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", coNumW)
.attr("height", coNumH)
.append("g").classed("no-select", true)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let radio = d3.select('input[name="options"]:checked').property("value");
let timeRange = radio;

let start = moment().subtract(timeRange, 'hours').format('LLL');
const end = moment().format('LLL');

timeRange = this.value;
dataset.forEach(function(d, i) {
            console.log('forEach timeRange: ', timeRange);
            d.start_date = new Date(d.start_date);
            d.end_date = new Date(d.end_date);
        if (d.start_date >= new Date(start) && d.end_date <= new Date(end)) {
            filtered.push(d);
            }
        });

xSc.domain([new Date(end), new Date(start)])
.range([0, w]);
ySc.domain(filtered.map(d => d.coNum)).padding(0.1);
console.log('xSc & ySc timeRange: ', timeRange)
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x Axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y Axis")
        .call(yAxis);

const tasks = svg.append("g").attr("class", "dataCont")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(filtered)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .on("mouseenter", showData);

tasks.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return xSc(d.start_date) + 2;  // + 2 is for padding
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
        return ySc(d.coNum);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return xSc(d.start_date) - xSc(d.end_date) - 2;
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return ySc.bandwidth();
        })
        .attr("fill", "green");

d3.selectAll("input")
      .on("change", change);

  function change() {

    timeRange = this.value;
    dataset.forEach(function(d, i) {
                console.log('forEach timeRange: ', timeRange);
                d.start_date = new Date(d.start_date);
                d.end_date = new Date(d.end_date);
            if (d.start_date >= new Date(start) && d.end_date <= new Date(end)) {
                filtered.push(d);
                }
            });

    xSc.domain([new Date(end), new Date(start)])
    .range([0, w]);
    ySc.domain(filtered.map(d => d.coNum)).padding(0.1);
    console.log('xSc & ySc timeRange: ', timeRange)
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x Axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y Axis")
            .call(yAxis);

    const tasks = svg.append("g").attr("class", "dataCont")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(filtered)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .on("mouseenter", showData);

    tasks.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return xSc(d.start_date) + 2;  // + 2 is for padding
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
            return ySc(d.coNum);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
                return xSc(d.start_date) - xSc(d.end_date) - 2;
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return ySc.bandwidth();
            })
            .attr("fill", "green");
        }

    function showData(d) {
        const dur = (d.end_date - d.start_date)/3600000;
        console.log("-" + d.coNum + "- start_date: " + dateFormat(d.start_date) + " || end_date: " + dateFormat(d.end_date))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in a project. I think the main thing you are missing is that when you change the data you need to remove the current chart and draw a new one. You may be able to make Angular do this for you, but I'm not sure how.

Personally, I would refactor the logic into something like `drawChart(filteredData)` and `filterData(unfilteredData, HOW TO FILTER)`. The initial draw on page load would be a call to `drawChart` with whatever data you want (it could go through `filterData()`. Your `change()` function would take the `HOW TO FILTER` from the radio button, pass it to `filterData()`, then remove the chart, then call `drawChart` with the filtered data. This architecture makes every draw of the chart the same and if you need changes to how the chart it drawn you can do it one place.

Example of new `change` function

```
change(howToFilter){
  var filteredData = filterData(dataset, howToFilter);
  CODE TO REMOVE THE CHART
  drawChart(filteredData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try that this morning and reply back when I have a working example.

Comment: I'm marking this as solved as this was the general idea as to what needed to be done.