# D3 update data of svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3. I am creating an interactive visualization. I want to update the data based on user's input and re-render (not-re-draww everything) the visualization.
Code for creating visualization:

```
cals = d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll("g")
    .data(yearlyData)  //I want to update this "yearlyData"
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id","svgGroup")
    .attr("transform",function(d,i){
        return "translate(0,"+(yOffset+(i*(height+calY)))+")";  
    })

dataRects = cals.append("g")
    .attr("id","dataDays")
    .selectAll("dataDays")
    .data(function(d){
        return d.values;   
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("id",function(d) {
        return format(d.date)+":"+d.DEPARTURE_DELAY;
    })
    .attr("stroke","#ccc")
    .attr("width",cellSize)
    .attr("height",cellSize)
    .attr("x", function(d){return xOffset+calX+(d3.time.weekOfYear(d.date) * cellSize);})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return calY+(d.date.getDay() * cellSize); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.DEPARTURE_DELAY<breaks[0]) {
            return colours[0];
        }
        for (i=0;i<breaks.length+1;i++){
            if (d.DEPARTURE_DELAY>=breaks[i]&&d.DEPARTURE_DELAY<breaks[i+1]){
                return colours[i];
            }
        }
        if (d.DEPARTURE_DELAY>breaks.length-1){
            return colours[breaks.length]   
        }
    })
```

I tried to use

```
dataRects.data(newData)  And

d3.select("body").select("svg").selectAll("g").data(newData);
```

in the Onclick() function, but these don't work. The source data is not changed. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 - Radio Buttons not Updating Data Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394752/d3-radio-buttons-not-updating-data-visualization)

Comment: That's solution is to remove everything and re-draw. But, I want to update the existing one.